# jQuery set and trigger option value based on the input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am using  https://www.geodata.solutions/ for getting country,state,city list 
And everything is working fine and i am able to save the data to databse

```
 <select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
 <select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
   <option value="">Select State</option>
 </select>
  <select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
   <option value="">Select City</option>
   </select>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/countrystatecity.js"></script>
```

Now i have to show the user to selected option

if      **$country , $state, $city** are the details i fetched from the data base

so i change the html to following

```
<select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
    <?php if($country!==""){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>" selected><?php echo $country; ?></option>
  <?php } else {  ?> 
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php } ?>
 </select>


<select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
 <?php if($state!==""){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $state; ?>" selected><?php echo $state; ?> 
    </option>
 <?php } else {  ?> 
 <option value="">Select State</option>
 <?php } ?>
  </select>
 <select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
    <?php if($city!==""){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>" selected><?php echo $city; ?> 
 </option>
  <?php } else {  ?> 
  <option value="">Select City</option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

But Now the this is they are not ablue to change the dropdown . How can i solve this

i tried this also

```
 <script>
    jQuery(function($){

      <?php if($country!==""){?>
    var mySelect=$("#countryId");
    mySelect.append(
         $('<option value="<?php echo $country;?>" selected><?php echo 
  $country;?></option>'));
     $('#countryId').trigger('change');
        <?php } ?>

  });
</script>
```

> 2) Question

I am checking for something that can integrate the country flag with the phone number field and i found https://intl-tel-input.com/. But now i have to select the country phone code automatically as per user change the country dropdown list in the fist select box . If there is any way we can make these each related ?